# What’s the meaning of “as much as?”

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Sentence:

> By 1997 a report in the Journal of the American Medical Association concluded that HRT extended life expectancy for postmenopausal women by ***as much as*** three years.

I don’t know if removing the “as much as” will affect the meaning. Why not take the phrase off if it doesn’t add more sense?

Comment: I thought the duplicate post was close enough to your question to answer it. If the post does not answer your question, please [edit] your post and explain why.

Comment: @Em. Thanks. It solved my problem